# How to use checkbox=true in DLRS relationship criteria?

Tags: soql, dlrs

I'm trying DLRS for the first time and I need help with an SOQL error.

I'm trying to count related contract records for each contact where tutor=true (in orange).
[image]

In my contract object, I have a  `select_tuteur__c`  lookup field, which is my Relationship field.

In DLRS, I'd like to run the roll-up only for Contacts where **tuteur__c=true**. This is where I'm getting an error. I searched the doc but I can't seem to find my mistake.

Can you help, please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't include quotes around the condition. That generates SOQL that looks like:

```
SELECT Id FROM whatever where 'tuteur__c=true'
```

Which isn't valid SOQL syntax.

Comment: Even without the quotes, I'm still getting an error message `error is 'value of filter criterion for field 'Tuteur__c' must be of type string and should be enclosed in quotes'`

Comment: @Sebbie Perhaps you're using the wrong field API name? This error comes from Salesforce, and it's telling you that the field's data type is string, and the query must look like `Tuteur__c = 'true'`.